# how to remove part of string in every lines

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I'm using sed to filter and correct a string of a list of files. I have a sorted list of file and I want to remove part of string in every lines. To do this task I'm using the solution with sed , but no result.
this is a sample of string.
arinare-naturale-sexy-e-p0rchissima-f-it63s1vg0/index.htmli
i must remove -it??????
I have a mac osx , with brew installed, using bash for script ,
but no result
thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the versions of your `sed` command that you thought *really* should work. Then we can help improve your understanding. DON'T reply in comments, and please use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu for correct `code/data/output/errMsgs` forrmatting. You should be able to explain your question with `echo "arinare-naturale-sexy-e-p0rchissima-f-it63s1vg0/index.html | sed 's/X/Y/'` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

---

*Apologies for the first script, I had overlooked the fact that you're under MacOS.  The script has been updated and tested under Linux Debian 11 with GNU SED in posix mode, as well as under MacOS Mojave, so this time it should work as expected on your end.*

---

Assuming that what you want is to remove the `-it*` suffix in the containing folder (the penultimate path component), then the command:

```
echo 'arinare-naturale-sexy-e-p0rchissima-f-it63s1vg0/index.htmli' | sed -e 's/-it[^-/]\{1,\}\(\/[^/\]*\)$/\1/'
```

produces the following output:

```
arinare-naturale-sexy-e-p0rchissima-f/index.htmli
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

the result of script sed is wrong .
myh result is this
iMac:Desktop oscarristolfi$ echo 'arinare-naturale-sexy-e-p0rchissima-f-it63s1vg0/index.htmli' | sed -e 's/-it[^-]+(/[^/]+)$/\1/'
arinare-naturale-sexy-e-p0rchissima-f-it63s1vg0/index.htmli
iMac:Desktop oscarristolfi$

doen't remove -it???????

why ?